# pandas: filter rows of DataFrame with operator chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Most operations in `pandas` can be accomplished with operator chaining (`groupby`, `aggregate`, `apply`, etc), but the only way I've found to filter rows is via normal bracket indexing

```
df_filtered = df[df['column'] == value]
```

This is unappealing as it requires I assign `df` to a variable before being able to filter on its values.  Is there something more like the following?

```
df_filtered = df.mask(lambda x: x['column'] == value)
```

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: dynamic expressions disallow any interpreter context help and are often a lower level of productivity/reliability.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, and your last line of code does not help either, but anyway:

"Chained" filtering is done by "chaining" the criteria in the boolean index.

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A  B  C  D
a  1  4  9  1
b  4  5  0  2
c  5  5  1  0
d  1  3  9  6

In [99]: df[(df.A == 1) & (df.D == 6)]
Out[99]:
   A  B  C  D
d  1  3  9  6
```

If you want to chain methods, you can add your own mask method and use that one.

```
In [90]: def mask(df, key, value):
   ....:     return df[df[key] == value]
   ....:

In [92]: pandas.DataFrame.mask = mask

In [93]: df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (4,4)), index=list('abcd'), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [95]: df.ix['d','A'] = df.ix['a', 'A']

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A  B  C  D
a  1  4  9  1
b  4  5  0  2
c  5  5  1  0
d  1  3  9  6

In [97]: df.mask('A', 1)
Out[97]:
   A  B  C  D
a  1  4  9  1
d  1  3  9  6

In [98]: df.mask('A', 1).mask('D', 6)
Out[98]:
   A  B  C  D
d  1  3  9  6
```

Comment: Great answer! So in ```(df.A == 1) & (df.D == 6)```, is the "&" an overloaded operator in Pandas?

Comment: indeed, see also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?#boolean-operators

Comment: That is a really nice solution - I wasn't even aware that you could jury-rig methods like that in python. A function like this would be really nice to have in Pandas itself.

Comment: The only problem i have with this is the use of `pandas.`. You should `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Indeed `import pandas as pd` is common practice now. I doubt it was when i answered the question.

Comment: @DaleSmith Out of curiosity, why does it matter if he imports it as pd or uses it as pandas?  Is it just a style preference or is there more?

Comment: Nice answer! I've applied it as a lambda :D
**pd.DataFrame.mask = lambda df, key, value: df[df[key] == value]**

Comment: The answer did taught something new. But I would prefer query() for now, as it would be easy to understand later.

Answer (score 158):

Filters can be chained using a Pandas [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 3), columns=['a','b','c'])
df_filtered = df.query('a > 0').query('0 < b < 2')
```

Filters can also be combined in a single query:

```
df_filtered = df.query('a > 0 and 0 < b < 2')
```

Comment: If you need to refer to python variables in your query, the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) says, "You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b".  Note that the following are valid: `df.query('a in list([1,2])')`, `s = set([1,2]); df.query('a in @s')`.

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like the query evaluation will fail if your column name has certain special characters: e.g. "Place.Name".

Comment: Chaining is what query is designed for.

Comment: @teichert you can use backtick as described in this post(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167183/how-to-reference-a-pandas-column-that-has-a-dot-in-the-name)

Comment: @KHKim Nice! It looks like that support for dotted names in backticks was added in [v1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Answer (score 75):

The answer from @lodagro is great. I would extend it by generalizing the mask function as:

```
def mask(df, f):
  return df[f(df)]
```

Then you can do stuff like:

```
df.mask(lambda x: x[0] < 0).mask(lambda x: x[1] > 0)
```

Comment: A useful generalization!  I wish it were integrated directly into `DataFrame`s already!

Answer (score 40):

Since [version 0.18.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) the `.loc` method accepts a callable for selection. Together with lambda functions you can create very flexible chainable filters:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[lambda df: df.A == 80]  # equivalent to df[df.A == 80] but chainable

df.sort_values('A').loc[lambda df: df.A > 80].loc[lambda df: df.B > df.A]
```

If all you're doing is filtering, you can also omit the `.loc`.

Answer (score 33):

pandas provides two alternatives to Wouter Overmeire's answer which do not require any overriding. One is `.loc[.]` with a callable, as in

```
df_filtered = df.loc[lambda x: x['column'] == value]
```

the other is `.pipe()`, as in

```
df_filtered = df.pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x['column'] == value])
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found so far. This allows for easy chaining and it is completely independent of the dataframe name, while maintaining a minimal syntax check (unlike "query"). Really neat approach, thanks.

Comment: +1 This should really be the accepted answer. It's built-in to pandas and requires no monkey-patching, and is the most flexible. I would also add that you can have your callable return an iterable of indexes as well, not just a boolean series.

Comment: Great answer, if anyone need with two columns, follows: pandasDF.loc[lambda n: (n['col1'] == 'value') | (n[col2']=='value')]

Comment: Thank you for a simple answer that works with method chaining and the additional comments on how to include multiple conditions to filter on!

Answer (score 18):

I offer this for additional examples.  This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159296/

I'll add other edits to make this post more useful.

[**`pandas.DataFrame.query`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
`query` was made for exactly this purpose.  Consider the dataframe `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 5)),
    columns=list('ABCDE')
)

df

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  2  7  3  8
1  7  0  6  8  6
2  0  2  0  4  9
3  7  3  2  4  3
4  3  6  7  7  4
5  5  3  7  5  9
6  8  7  6  4  7
7  6  2  6  6  5
8  2  8  7  5  8
9  4  7  6  1  5
```

Let's use `query` to filter all rows where `D > B`

```
df.query('D > B')

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  2  7  3  8
1  7  0  6  8  6
2  0  2  0  4  9
3  7  3  2  4  3
4  3  6  7  7  4
5  5  3  7  5  9
7  6  2  6  6  5
```

Which we chain

```
df.query('D > B').query('C > B')
# equivalent to
# df.query('D > B and C > B')
# but defeats the purpose of demonstrating chaining

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  2  7  3  8
1  7  0  6  8  6
4  3  6  7  7  4
5  5  3  7  5  9
7  6  2  6  6  5
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159296/ 
Is there something missing from that answer that you think should be clarified?

Answer (score 12):

My answer is similar to the others. If you do not want to create a new function you can use what pandas has defined for you already. Use the pipe method.

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d[d['column'] == value])
```

Comment: **THIS** is what you want if you want to chain commands such as `a.join(b).pipe(lambda df: df[df.column_to_filter == 'VALUE'])`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same question except that I wanted to combine the criteria into an OR condition.  The format given by Wouter Overmeire combines the criteria into an AND condition such that both must be satisfied:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A  B  C  D
a  1  4  9  1
b  4  5  0  2
c  5  5  1  0
d  1  3  9  6

In [99]: df[(df.A == 1) & (df.D == 6)]
Out[99]:
   A  B  C  D
d  1  3  9  6
```

But I found that, if you wrap each condition in `(... == True)` and join the criteria with a pipe, the criteria are combined in an OR condition, satisfied whenever either of them is true:

```
df[((df.A==1) == True) | ((df.D==6) == True)]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `df[(df.A==1) | (df.D==6)]` be sufficient for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: No, it wouldn't because it give bollean results (True vs False) instead of as it is above which filter all data which satisfy the condition. Hope that I made it clear.

Answer (score 7):

Just want to add a demonstration using `loc` to filter not only by rows but also by columns and some merits to the chained operation.

The code below can filter the rows by value.

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df['column'] == value]
```

By modifying it a bit you can filter the columns as well.

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df['column'] == value, ['year', 'column']]
```

So why do we want a chained method? The answer is that it is simple to read if you have many operations. For example,

```
res =  df\
    .loc[df['station']=='USA', ['TEMP', 'RF']]\
    .groupby('year')\
    .agg(np.nanmean)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to apply all of the common boolean masks as well as a general purpose mask you can chuck the following in a file and then simply assign them all as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame = apply_masks()
```

Usage:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
A.le_mask("A", 0.7).ge_mask("B", 0.2)... (May be repeated as necessary
```

It's a little bit hacky but it can make things a little bit cleaner if you're continuously chopping and changing datasets according to filters.
There's also a general purpose filter adapted from Daniel Velkov above in the gen_mask function which you can use with lambda functions or otherwise if desired.

File to be saved (I use masks.py):

```
import pandas as pd

def eq_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] == value]

def ge_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] >= value]

def gt_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] > value]

def le_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] <= value]

def lt_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] < value]

def ne_mask(df, key, value):
    return df[df[key] != value]

def gen_mask(df, f):
    return df[f(df)]

def apply_masks():

    pd.DataFrame.eq_mask = eq_mask
    pd.DataFrame.ge_mask = ge_mask
    pd.DataFrame.gt_mask = gt_mask
    pd.DataFrame.le_mask = le_mask
    pd.DataFrame.lt_mask = lt_mask
    pd.DataFrame.ne_mask = ne_mask
    pd.DataFrame.gen_mask = gen_mask

    return pd.DataFrame

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is more hackish in terms of implementation, but I find it much cleaner in terms of usage, and it is certainly more general than the others proposed.

https://github.com/toobaz/generic_utils/blob/master/generic_utils/pandas/where.py

You don't need to download the entire repo: saving the file and doing

```
from where import where as W
```

should suffice. Then you use it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, True],
                   [3, 4, False], 
                   [5, 7, True]],
                  index=range(3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# On specific column:
print(df.loc[W['a'] > 2])
print(df.loc[-W['a'] == W['b']])
print(df.loc[~W['c']])
# On entire - or subset of a - DataFrame:
print(df.loc[W.sum(axis=1) > 3])
print(df.loc[W[['a', 'b']].diff(axis=1)['b'] > 1])
```

A slightly less stupid usage example:

```
data = pd.read_csv('ugly_db.csv').loc[~(W == '$null$').any(axis=1)]
```

By the way: even in the case in which you are just using boolean cols,

```
df.loc[W['cond1']].loc[W['cond2']]
```

can be much more efficient than

```
df.loc[W['cond1'] & W['cond2']]
```

because it evaluates `cond2` only where `cond1` is `True`.

DISCLAIMER: I first gave this answer [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516891/2858145) because I hadn't seen this.

Answer (score 3):

> This is unappealing as it requires I assign `df` to a variable before being able to filter on its values.

```
df[df["column_name"] != 5].groupby("other_column_name")
```

seems to work: you can nest the `[]` operator as well. Maybe they added it since you asked the question.

Comment: This makes little sense in a chain because `df` now doesn't necessarily reference the output of the previour part of te chain.

Comment: @DaanLuttik: agreed, it is not chaining, but nesting. Better for you?

Answer (score 3):

So the way I see it is that you do two things when sub-setting your data ready for analysis.

- get rows
- get columns

Pandas has a number of ways of doing each of these and some techniques that help get rows **and** columns. For new Pandas users it can be confusing as there is so much choice.

Do you use iloc, loc, brackets, query, isin, np.where, mask etc...

**Method chaining**

Now method chaining is a great way to work when data wrangling. In R they have a simple way of doing it, you `select()` columns and you `filter()` rows.

So if we want to keep things simple in Pandas why not use the `filter()` for columns and the `query()` for rows. These both return dataframes and so no need to mess-around with boolean indexing, no need to add `df[ ]` round the return value.

So what does that look like:-

```
df.filter(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).query("col1 == 'sometext'")
```

You can then chain on any other methods like `groupby`, `dropna()`, `sort_values()`, `reset_index()` etc etc.

By being consistent and using `filter()` to get your columns and `query()` to get your rows it will be easier to read your code when coming back to it after a time.

**But filter can select rows?**

Yes this is true but by default `query()` get rows and `filter()` get columns. So if you stick with the default there is no need to use the `axis=` parameter.

**query()**

query() can be used with both `and`/`or` `&`/`|` you can also use comparison operators `> , < , >= , <=, ==, !=`. You can also use Python in, not in.

You can pass a list to query using @my_list

Some examples of using query to get rows

```
df.query('A > B')

df.query('a not in b')

df.query("series == '2206'")

df.query("col1 == @mylist")

df.query('Salary_in_1000 >= 100 & Age < 60 & FT_Team.str.startswith("S").values')
```

**filter()**

So filter is basicly like using bracket `df[]` or `df[[]]` in that it uses the labels to select columns. But it does more than the bracket notation.

filter has `like=` param so as to help select columns with partial names.

```
df.filter(like='partial_name',)
```

filter also has regex to help with selection

```
df.filter(regex='reg_string')
```

So to sum up this way of working might not work for ever situation e.g. if you want to use indexing/slicing then iloc is the way to go. But this does seem to be a solid way of working and can simplify your workflow and code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also leverage the *numpy* library for logical operations. Its pretty fast.

```
df[np.logical_and(df['A'] == 1 ,df['B'] == 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set your columns to search as indexes, then you can use `DataFrame.xs()` to take a cross section. This is not as versatile as the `query` answers, but it might be useful in some situations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(3, size=(10, 5)),
    columns=list('ABCDE')
)

df
# Out[55]: 
#    A  B  C  D  E
# 0  0  2  2  2  2
# 1  1  1  2  0  2
# 2  0  2  0  0  2
# 3  0  2  2  0  1
# 4  0  1  1  2  0
# 5  0  0  0  1  2
# 6  1  0  1  1  1
# 7  0  0  2  0  2
# 8  2  2  2  2  2
# 9  1  2  0  2  1

df.set_index(['A', 'D']).xs([0, 2]).reset_index()
# Out[57]: 
#    A  D  B  C  E
# 0  0  2  2  2  2
# 1  0  2  1  1  0
```