# How can I filter lines on load in Pandas read_csv function?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter which lines of a CSV to be loaded into memory using pandas?  This seems like an option that one should find in `read_csv`.  Am I missing something?

Example: we've a CSV with a timestamp column and we'd like to load just the lines that with a timestamp greater than a given constant.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

There isn't an option to filter the rows before the CSV file is loaded into a pandas object.

You can either load the file and then filter using `df[df['field'] > constant]`, or if you have a very large file and you are worried about memory running out, then use an iterator and apply the filter as you concatenate chunks of your file e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
iter_csv = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['field'] > constant] for chunk in iter_csv])
```

You can vary the `chunksize` to suit your available memory. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) for more details.

Comment: for `chunk['filed']>constant` can I sandwich it between 2 constant values? E.g.: constant1 > chunk['field'] > constant2. Or can I use 'in range' ?

Comment: Try: ``chunk[(chunk['field'] > constant2)&(chunk['field']<constant1)]``

Comment: Is this missing a `.loc`? `chunk.loc[chunk['field'] > constant]`

Comment: You can use boolean masks with or without `.loc`. I don't think `.loc` existed back in 2012, but I guess these days using `.loc` is a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't find a straight-forward way to do it within context of `read_csv`. However, `read_csv` returns a DataFrame, which can be filtered by selecting rows by boolean vector `df[bool_vec]`:

```
filtered = df[(df['timestamp'] > targettime)]
```

This is selecting all rows in df (assuming df is any DataFrame, such as the result of a `read_csv` call, that at least contains a datetime column `timestamp`) for which the values in the `timestamp` column are greater than the value of targettime. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining).

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I have the feeling this would be extremely heavy on memory usage.

Comment: The question is about filtering the data on loading, I don't know why so many upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the accepted answer is to apply read_csv() to a StringIO, obtained by filtering the input file.

```
with open(<file>) as f:
    text = "\n".join([line for line in f if <condition>])

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
```

This solution is often faster than the accepted answer when the filtering condition retains only a small portion of the lines

Comment: How does the `<condition>` work here? `text = "\n".join([line for line in f if df['column']=='Hello'])` Like that? edit: no it doesn't work. `TypeError: string indices must be integers
`

Comment: No. Suppose 'column' is the third column in your CSV file, assuming ',' is the field-separator, write:

`with open(<file>) as f:
   text = "\n".join([line for line in f if line.split(',')[2] == "Hello"])`

Answer (score 4):

If the filtered range is contiguous (as it usually is with time(stamp) filters), then the fastest solution is to hard-code the range of rows. Simply combine `skiprows=range(1, start_row)` with `nrows=end_row` parameters. Then the import takes seconds where the accepted solution would take minutes. A few experiments with the initial `start_row` are not a huge cost given the savings on import times. Notice we kept header row by using `range(1,..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have the below dataframe

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Sarath |
|  2 | Peter  |
|  3 | James  |
+----+--------+
```

If you need to filter a record where `Id = 1` then you can use the below code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv', sep = '|')
df = df [(df ["Id"] == 1)]
```

This will produce the below output.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Sarath |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Apparently he is asking for a selective method "on load." Your solution would load all the data to memory and then do the filtering.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on linux you can use grep.

```
# to import either on Python2 or Python3
import pandas as pd
from time import time # not needed just for timing
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO


def zgrep_data(f, string):
    '''grep multiple items f is filepath, string is what you are filtering for'''

    grep = 'grep' # change to zgrep for gzipped files
    print('{} for {} from {}'.format(grep,string,f))
    start_time = time()
    if string == '':
        out = subprocess.check_output([grep, string, f])
        grep_data = StringIO(out)
        data = pd.read_csv(grep_data, sep=',', header=0)

    else:
        # read only the first row to get the columns. May need to change depending on 
        # how the data is stored
        columns = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', nrows=1, header=None).values.tolist()[0]    

        out = subprocess.check_output([grep, string, f])
        grep_data = StringIO(out)

        data = pd.read_csv(grep_data, sep=',', names=columns, header=None)

    print('{} finished for {} - {} seconds'.format(grep,f,time()-start_time))
    return data
```

Comment: Using grep is seriously bad choice for several reasons. 1) it's slow 2) it's not portable 3) it's not pandas or python (you can use regular expressions right inside python) which is why I downvoted your answer

Comment: Your solution doesn't work on all platforms and also it includes Grep. This is the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score -6):

You can specify `nrows` parameter.

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=100)`

This code works well in version 0.20.3.

Comment: OP is asking how to filter not limit the number of lines read. This is why I downvoted your answer.