# Date selection in large csv time series files

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas

I'm dealing with some large CSV files. Basically I have two for the year 2009 and 2010. I read these both is seperatly using pandas, and then append the 2010 file to the end of the 2009 dataframe.

To do this I use the function:

```
def import_data():
     with open(file_A, 'r') as f:
         reader = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', parse_dates=({'Date_Time': [0]}) )
     with open (file_B, 'r') as B:
         reader2= pd.read_csv(B, sep=',', parse_dates=({'Date_Time': [0]}))   
     reader=reader.append(reader2)

     return reader
```

Basically, I then do some processing, resampling the data. However, all this takes such a long time due to the length of the files.

Is there a way to select certain rows based on defined inputs? e.g. just dates 01/10/2009 - 01/02/2010? Dates are all in the first column of the csv.

I know that this is possible for the columns using `use_cols` within `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: I'm sure it is just a copy/paste error, but you have an erroneous bracket in your append statement

Comment: yeh, copy paste error, but thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/pandas-filter-lines-on-load-in-read-csv

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making them into iterators?

```
from itertools import chain

def import_data():
     with open(file_A, 'r') as f:
         reader = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', parse_dates=({'Date_Time': [0]}), iterator=True)
     with open (file_B, 'r') as B:
         reader2= pd.read_csv(B, sep=',', parse_dates=({'Date_Time': [0]}), iterator=True)
     return chain(reader, reader2)

desired_range = [row for row in import_data() if row >= start_date and row <= end_date]
```