# how to remove all rows in the CSV file which a value is greater than another?

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have a csv file, 300 lines:

`ID,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
1,1.80,80,78,78,82,82
2,1.60,58,56,60,60,56
3,1.90,100,98,102,98,102`

I want a file to delete all lines where the column MEAN WEIGHT> 75 and obtain another new file

`ID,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
1,1.80,80,78,78,82,82
3,1.90,100,98,102,98,102`

Comment: Panda is suited for doing this kind of jobs but it also can be done using normal csv module

Comment: You can check solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/pandas-filter-lines-on-load-in-read-csv

Answer (score 2):

if you're open to non Python solutions and access to bash shell or `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '$3>75' filename 

ID,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
1,1.80,80,78,78,82,82
3,1.90,100,98,102,98,102
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain python:

```
orig = open('original.csv', 'r')
modi = open('modified.csv', 'w')

#header
modi.write(orig.readline())

# data lines
for line in old:
    if float(line.split(',')[2]) <= 75:
        modi.write(line)

orig.close()
modi.close()
```

Comment: i tried but only appear the header.in the new file.

Answer (score 1):

as @Vignesh Kalai suggested, use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", sep=",")

df[ df["MEAN WEIGHT"] > 75 ].to_csv("yournewfile.csv", index=False)
```

And  it's done.

P.S. You're asking for values less than 75 but you're displaying the opposit .If it is the first case replace "`> 75`" by "`<= 75`".

Comment: It works but add a new column                                           ,ID,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
0,1,1.8,80,78,78,82,82
2,3,1.9,100,98,102,98,102

Comment: @PedroSousa Sure, use index = False (See Edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `csv` library as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Write the header
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for cols in csv_input:
        if int(cols[2]) <= 75:    # Keep weights <= 75
            csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

So with the data you have given, you will get the following `output.csv` file:

```
ID,HEIGHT,MEAN WEIGHT,20-Nov-2002,05-Mar-2003,09-Apr-2003,23-Jul-2003
2,1.60,58,56,60,60,56
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution which prints to screen, similar to karakfa's Awk solution:

```
perl -F, -ane 'print if $. == 1 or $F[4] > 75' filename
```

The `@F` autosplit array starts at index `$F[0]` while awk fields start with `$1`

This variation edits the file in-place:

```
perl -i -F, -ane 'print if $. == 1 or $F[4] > 75' filename
```

This variation edits the file in-place, and makes a backup `filename.bak`

```
perl -i.bak -F, -ane 'print if $. == 1 or $F[4] > 75' filename
```