# Reading huge csv files efficiently?

Tags: csv, pandas, bigdata

I know how to use pandas to read files with CSV extension. When reading a large file i get an out of memory error. The file is  3.8 million rows and 6.4 millions columns file. There is mostly genome data in the file of large populations.

How can I overcome the problem, what is standard practice and how do I select the appropriate tool for this. Can I process a file this big with pandas, or there is another tool?

Comment: Do you need to read the whole file? you can pass `chunksize` param to `read_csv` and process the chunks

Comment: Maybe help [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542977/pandas-groupby-with-sum-on-large-csv-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Spark to distribute in-memory processing of csv files https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv. Take a look at [ADAM's](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam) approach for distributed genomic data processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

```
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i in datareader:
        #process each line
        #You now only hold one row in memory, instead of your thousands of lines
```