# Sum of different CSV columns in python

Tags: python, csv

I am quite new to Python and therefore this might seem easy but I am really stuck here.

I have a CSV file with values in a [525599 x 74] matrix. For each column of the 74 columns I would like to have the total sum of all 525599 values saved in one list.

I could not figure out the right way to iterate over each column and save the sum of each column in a list.

Comment: this can be done very simply with pandas (you should be able to read the docs)

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602344/sum-each-column-of-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you :

- create a columnTotal integer array (one index for each column).
- read the file line by line, per line:

  - Split the line using the comma as separator
  - Convert the splitted string parts to integers
  - Add the value of each column to the columnTotal array's colum index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to python I won't use any fancy libraries like pandas or numpy. But you should definitely check those out some time

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('your_csv.csv', 'r'))
sums = [0] * 74
for row in reader:
    for i, element in enumerate(row):
        sums[i] += int(element)
print(sums)
```

Comment: this just doesn't work. csv file contains strings, you have to convert to float / int first. And hardcoding the list at start is very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah I missed the conversion. Just edited it. Now... Do we really care about good convention when the guy is just learning Python? I just wanted to make it simple for the guy. If I cared about it I would probably just use pandas