# Creating a filter while creating a dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large dataset (~15GB zipped). What is the most efficient way of random sampling from this dataset using Pandas? Currently I have the following way;

```
df = pd.read_csv (file, names = []
    , sep = '|', nrows=10000000)
```

However this really does not serve my need. Additionally is there a way I can filter the data before creating the dataframe?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: for filter you probably can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13653490/1744834