# pandas read_csv and keep only certain rows (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware of the skiprows that allows you to pass a list with the indices of the rows to skip. However, I have the index of the rows I want to keep.

Say that my cvs file looks like this for millions of rows:

```
  A B
0 1 2
1 3 4
2 5 6
3 7 8
4 9 0
```

The list of indices i would like to load are only 2,3, so

```
index_list = [2,3]
```

The input for the skiprows function would be [0,1,4]. However, I only have available [2,3].

I am trying something like:

```
pd.read_csv(path, skiprows = ~index_list)
```

but no luck.. any suggestions?

thank and I appreciate all the help,

Comment: Can you provide the exact code instead of a template?

Comment: @ Sreejith hopefully its more readable now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you would need to find the number of lines first, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019572/2029132).

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))
```

Then you would need to delete the indices of `index_list`:

```
to_exclude = [i for i in num_lines if i not in index_list]
```

and then load your data:

```
pd.read_csv(path, skiprows = to_exclude)
```

Comment: Thank you gabra I figured I would have to do something like this. It seems odd that there is skiprows but not one to read certain rows

Comment: @dleal I agree with you. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13651117/2029132) also relates to your question.

Comment: you'd need to put `[i for i in range(num_lines) if i not in index_list]` right ? num_lines is not iterable, is an integer

Answer (score 20):

You can pass in a lambda function in the `skiprows` argument. For example:

```
rows_to_keep = [2,3]
pd.read_csv(path, skiprows = lambda x: x not in rows_to_keep)
```

You can read more about it in the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: [I did some testing](https://i.imgur.com/ljLEmkt.jpg) and found that for the argument `skiprows`, **passing a list is much faster than passing a lambda function.** Passing a list appears to be O(1), whereas passing a lambda func is O(N). So for very large CSV files, I strongly recommend generating the list of rows to skip from a list of known rows to keep first, like gabra's answer. *(Results as of pandas v1.4.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution to this could be to call `.loc` right after `read_csv`. Something like this

```
index_to_keep = [2, 4]
pd.read_csv(path).loc[index_to_keep]
```

Note:
This is a slower approach, as here the entire file will be first loaded in the memory and then only seleted rows will be selected.