# how to read only a chunk of csv file fast?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653490/3512538) on how to read only a chunk of CSV file with `pandas`.

The suggestion to use `pd.read_csv('./input/test.csv' , iterator=True, chunksize=1000)` works excellent but it returns a `<class 'pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader'>`, so I'm converting it to dataframe with `pd.concat(pd.read_csv('./input/test.csv' , iterator=True, chunksize=25))` but that takes as much time as reading the file in the first place!

Any suggestions on how to read only a chunk of the file fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.read_csv('./input/test.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)` returns an iterator.  You can use the `next` function to grab the next one

```
reader = pd.read_csv('./input/test.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)

next(reader)
```

This is often used in a for loop for processing one chunk at a time.

```
for df in pd.read_csv('./input/test.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000):
    pass
```

Comment: Trying to convert the iterator to a dataframe using `pd.concat` forced it to read the whole file?

Comment: Yes.  It also highlights that you can pass iterators to `pd.concat` which is handy to know.  Using `next` on the iterator limits the reading to one chuck at a time.