# How to extract specific portion of CSV file using row key with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, extract

I have a huge CSV file with 10000 rows and 500 columns. I want to extract the data from header to the row which contains `device_boot`. I want to eliminate all rows after `device_boot`.

Example:

```
Name,Time,status,..
start,05:06:2018 10:10:23,good,..
start,05:06:2018 10:11:23,good,..
failure,05:06:2018 11:10:25,critical,..
device_boot,05:06:2018 13:11:25,reboot,..
start,05:06:2018 13:13:23,good,..
start,05:06:2018 13:16:23,good,..
```

So, I need to maintain in CSV file up to `device_boot` line (row) using pandas. I am able to remove the specific row on that keyword, but not able to extract up to that portion using `pd.drop(...)`.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: why dont you record the index number, that would be things easier i think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter lines on load in Pandas read\_csv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/how-can-i-filter-lines-on-load-in-pandas-read-csv-function)

Comment: In pandas you can use ```nrows```. Something like: ```data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", nrows=1312)```. Just find the row count, i would have used simple bash commands like ```wc`` or a simple for loop..

Comment: Yes,i know the row number and extract the rows upto keyword, but sometime not able to know the row number due to huge file.   For getting rows based on index, I used, df = pd.read_csv(/home/ubuntu1/output.csv',low_memory=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode8', nrows=590)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print(df.loc[:df['Name'].gt('device_boot').idxmin()+1,:])
```

Output will be expected output.

**Update:**

```
print(df.loc[:df.index[df['Name']=='device_boot'].tolist()[-1],:])
```

And that contains the `'device_boot'` row, if want to remove it:

```
print(df.loc[:df.index[df['Name']=='device_boot'].tolist()[-1]-1,:])
```

Comment: yes,your answer do the filtering of the specific row only, but what my expectation is "how to extract rows upto  device_boot word in the firstrow". In some csv files, device_boot will appear more than one time also, I need to extract all rows in the csv file upto last device_boot appear in first column.

Answer (score 0):

I findout the index of the keyword,like

```
val = df.loc[df['name']=='device_boot'].index
print val
```

Then, use that row index and retrive only until that variable,

```
rowretrive_index = val1+50  // any extra rows can be added here.
print rowretrive_index

df1 = df.iloc[1:rowretrive_index]
df1.to_csv('/out.csv',',',dtype='unicode8')
```

Hope it will useful.
Thanks,
Sundar