# How to extract/filter rows of a csv file based on some particular keywords?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data in the form like

How do I separate or filter the rows based on the keywords of the genre(horror, thriller, etc) and store them for further processing(sorting)?[image]

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] to make this as useful as possible.  Also, I'm sure there is a duplicate question somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter lines on load in Pandas read\_csv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/how-can-i-filter-lines-on-load-in-pandas-read-csv-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe do:

```
f = open("myfile.csv", "r")
romance_mov = []

for line in f:

    if "romance" in line.split(",")[4].lower():
        romance_mov.append(line)
f.close()
```

Which would give you a list `romance_mov` with all the lines that are of genre 'romance'.

EDIT: For sorting the lines based on the value in hitFlop, you could then do:

```
import numpy as np

# Extract the hitFlop value for each row
hitFlop = []
for item in romance_mov:
    hitFlop.append(int(item.split(",")[-1]))

# Obtain the sorted indexes
idx_sorted = np.argsort(hitFlop)
# Sort the romance movies
romance_mov_sorted = np.asarray(romance_mov)[idx_sorted]
```

Comment: How can I sort the data saved in romance_mov according to the values of hitFlop?

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain how to do the sorting after.