# Reading specific rows out of a panda dataframe using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I need to pull specific rows out of and into a new dataframe.
These rows are in a list that look something like this:[42 50 52 59 60 62]

I am creating the dataframe from a .csv file but as far as I can tell there is not a way to designate the row numbers when reading the .csv and creating the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35',index_col = False, header = None )
```

Here's a portion of the dataframe:

```
                    0
0      1 269 245 44 5
1      2 293 393 33 5
2     3 295 175 67 12
3      4 298 415 33 5
4    5 304 392 213 11
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/how-can-i-filter-lines-on-load-in-pandas-read-csv-function will help. You will have to read the whole file and then filter out the rows of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Use `skiprows` with a callable:

```
import pandas as pd

keep_rows = [42 50 52 59 60 62]

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35', 
                 header=None
                 skiprows=lambda x: x not in keep_rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pandas `read_cvs` expects a true file, and not a mere line generator, so it is not easy to select only a bunch of lines. But you can to that at Python level easily:

```
lines = [line for i, line in enumerate(open('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35'), 1)
         if i in [42 50 52 59 60 62]]
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),index_col = False, header = None )
```

---

You can also use `skiprows` to ignore all the lines except the ones to keep:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35',index_col = False, 
                 header = None, skiprows=lambda x: x not in [42 50 52 59 60 62])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately I'm getting an error when I'm trying: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/Pandas to createxyt.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),index_col = False, header = None )
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: @mattp: If you are using Python 2.x, you must use `io.BytesIO` instead of `io.StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [42, 50, 52, 59, 60, 62] 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35',
                 index_col= False,
                 header=None,
                 nrows=max(my_list) + 1).iloc[mylist]
```