# Deleting multiple columns of CSV files based on certain conditions on Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file containing multiple columns(almost 100). How can I filter multiple columns at once using certain criteria in Python? To be more precise, many of the columns are of no use to me. How can the file be filtered?

PS: I am a beginner user.

Comment: Please always give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter lines on load in Pandas read\_csv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/how-can-i-filter-lines-on-load-in-pandas-read-csv-function)

Comment: @MayankPorwal, the question you've send is about filtering lines and the question posted is concerning filtering columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the zero values from your dataframe column, you should follow following steps, (suppose you dataframe has name `df`)

1. Replace all the zero values to `nan` first

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
```

2. Drop the `nan` value using `dropna` method in `pandas`

```py
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

The parameter `axis=1` is for assigning drop rule for `columnwise`. And the `how=all` for checking all the values inside this column.

In this way, Single line answer is below

```py
df = df.replace(0, np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how=all)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have following content in csv file

> Col1,Col2, Col3
>   1,a,0
>   2,b,0
>   3,d,1

Read it in pandas dataframe using following script

```py
import pandas as pd  

df=pd.read_csv(file)
```

To see the columns in dataframe df use

```py
print(df.columns)
```

This will give you the column names in df in form of list, in this case ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

To retain only specific columns (for example col1 and col3) you can use

```py
df=df [ [ "col1","col3"] ]
```

Now if you print (df.columns) it will only have ['col1', 'col3']

**Edited in reply to the comment:**

If you want to delete the columns that fulfil certain condition you can use the following script

```py
for column in df.columns:

    if 0 in df[column].values: # This will check if 0 is in values of column,  you can add any condition you want here

    print('Deleting column', column) # I assume you want to delete the column that fulfills the condition

    df=df.drop(columns=column) # This statement will delete the column fulfilling the condition
print("df after deleting columns:")
print(df)
```

It will print

> Deleting column col3
>
> df after deleting columns:
>
> col1, col2
>
> 1,a
>
> 2,b
>
> 3,c

Comment: I have to check if col 1,col 2,...........,col X satisfy some conditions. How can I do that?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can see the script how to check which columns satisfy some condition. Please vote up if it was helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the csv file as pandas dataframe and then play around. Please have a look at the pandas documentation on how to read csv files. You can extract the column you want based on their header names. Also you can apply mathematical operations in a fast way. Though, for large scale calculations, note that python is not suitable since each time you import your libraries.

Comment: I have multiple columns whose value is zero. I need to remove all the columns having zero as its value. I didn't find it at pandas documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have a dataframe `df` with columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` and you want only `col1` and `col2`, you could do -

```
new_df = df[['col1', 'col2']]
```