# Import specific rows from 4gb csv using python (without import entire file)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, jupyter

I have 4gb csv file and i need to extract only the rows with a specific date(ex. 31.12.2020) from column 'Date'. I would like not to import entire file on jupyter but directly import specific rows from local to jupyter. It is possible?
Thank you

Comment: Did you consider using a different format like hdf5 instead?

Comment: It may be possible but I wouldn't do this. Use a command line program like grep to get what you need into another smaller file. You can execute bash commands in Jupyter with %%bash in the cell.

Comment: A `csv` is a text file.  `numpy` and `pandas` loads are designed to read the whole thing, though you can also specify line ranges (start, number etc).  For a line with a specific value, you'd have to read the file, line by line, until you find the desired line.  In other words, such a file doesn't have an index that would quickly tell you which line to load.

Comment: There's a method here for loading with chunks and concatenating. You could modify it to your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651117/how-can-i-filter-lines-on-load-in-pandas-read-csv-function