# Iterate through columns and rename according to a rule

Tags: python, pandas, glob

In the following snippet of code, I am trying to rename some columns (containing `Hosted Meetings`) to `Hosted Meetings [date]`. This is what happens when I print all the `i`'s. However, it does not save this to `df`.

```
all_users_sheets_hosts = []

for f in glob.glob("./users-export-*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_users_sheets_hosts.append(df)
    j = re.search('(\d+)', f)
    for i in df.columns.values:
        if 'Hosted Meetings' in i:
            i = ('Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator `i` is a copy of the array value, not a pointer. One way to fix this would be to `enumerate` through the index rather than the values themselves:

```
for i, val in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    if 'Hosted Meetings' in val:
        df.columns[i] = ('Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))
```

However in any case it's a good illustration of the advantages of a more functional style. In your case, you can treat the columns as a pandas Series of type `str`, and hence you can use the vectorised `replace` on it, to rename your columns in one statement:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.*Hosted Meeings.*', 
                                    'Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))
```

Comment: Wonderful. New to python so this helps me learn and with my problem

Comment: no worries, i've added a bit more to show you how to fix your loop, however it's almost always better (faster/safer/less buggy) to use a vectorised operation if you can work out how.

Comment: Also, how would I go about looking for all rows in multiple columns that fit some criteria?

Comment: there's a few different ways, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining looks like it covers some of them (`query` is my favourite wherever possible)

Comment: Thank you @maxymoo , though I'm a bit confused by this, having never used queries or masks before. Say I want to delete rows where any cell, which is in a column whose title contains 'X', contains the word 'acme'. My current thinking is to add a for loop (for column titles containing X), then use a previously defined mask to remove 'acme' rows. Is there a better way?

Comment: yeah that's kind of a tricky query, I can't think of a better way off the top of my head; ask it as another question if you like and someone else might be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Update on the previous answer:

The current answer will now raise an exception: **index does not support mutable operations**

Change:

```
df.columns[i] = ('Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))
```

to:

```
df.columns.values[i] = ('Hosted Meetings' + ' ' + j.group(1))
```