# Variable lengths don't respond to filters...then they do. Can someone explain?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Edit: All sorted, [Imanol Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764322/imanol-luengo) set me straight. [Here's the end result, in all it's glory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU0A6.png).

I don't understand the counts of my variables, maybe someone can explain? I'm filtering two columns of pass/fails for two locations. I want a count of all 4 pass/fails.

Here's the header of the columns. There are 126 values in total:

```
  WT Result School
0         p  Milan
1         p   Roma
2         p  Milan
3         p  Milan
4         p   Roma
```

Code so far:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data[['WT Result', 'School']])
data2.dropna(inplace=True)

# Milan Counts
m_p = (data2['School']=='Milan') & (data2['WT Result']=='p')
milan_p = (m_p==True)
milan_pass = np.count_nonzero(milan_p)   # Count of Trues for Milano

# Rome Counts
r_p = (data2['School']=='Roma') & (data2['WT Result']=='p')
rome_p = (r_p==True)
rome_pass = np.count_nonzero(rome_p)   # Count of Trues for Rome
```

So what I've done, after stripping the excess columns (*data2*), is:

- filter by location and == 'p'             (vars *m_p* and *r_p*)
- filter then by ==True                     (vars *milan_p* and *rome_p*)
- Do a count_nonzero() for a count of 'True'  (vars *milan_pass* and *rome_pass*)

Here's what I don't understand - these are the lengths of the variables:

```
data2:  126 
m_p:  126 
r_p:  126 
milan_p:  126 
rome_p:  126 
milan_pass:  55 
rome_pass:  47
```

Why do the lengths remain 126 once the filtering starts? To me, this shows that neither the filtering by location or by 'p' worked. *But* when I do the final count_nonzero() the results are suddenly separated into location. What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You are not *filtering*, you are *masking*. Step by step:

```
m_p = (data2['School']=='Milan') & (data2['WT Result']=='p')
```

Here `m_p` is a boolean array with the same length of a column from `data2`. Each element of `m_p` is set to `True` if it satisfies those 2 conditions, or to `False` otherwise.

```
milan_p = (m_p==True)
```

The above line is completely redundant. `m_p` is already a boolean array, comparing it to `True` will just create a *copy* of it. Thus, `milan_p` will be another boolean array with the same length as `m_p`.

```
milan_pass = np.count_nonzero(milan_p)
```

This just prints the number of nonzeros (e.g. `True`) elements of `milan_p`. Ofcourse, it matches the number of elements that you want to filter, but you are not filtering anything here.

Exactly the same applies to `rome` condition.

---

If you want to [`filter rows in pandas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872393/764322), you have to slice the dataframe with your newly generated mask:

```
filtered_milan = data2[m_p]
```

or alternatively

```
filtered_milan = data2[milan_p] # as m_p == milan_p
```

The above lines select the rows that have a `True` value in the mask (or condition), ignoring the `False` rows in the process.

The same applies for the second problem, `rome`.

Comment: You're fantastic! Thank you for your time.