# How to remove the year part from 3rd column using python

Tags: python

In the image below, bd is the dataframe whose type is 
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
I'm using Pandas for this.
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here][1]

https://ibb.co/d4BRbk

Comment: you forget to upload the image and also show first what you have tried

Comment: Sorry about that. Now it's done.

Comment: show also what you have tried, and also see how to ask a question 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask'

Comment: @HimanshuPrakash Please [embded the image in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow). But also include your `DataFrame` + code as **code** (not image).

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining

Comment: sorry guys. I'm new to this stackoverflow thing. and about what I've tried for this question, actually I'm not able to figure out how to do it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module and replace both *year* and *years* with empty string:

```
df[3] = df[3].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\syear(s?)', '', x))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error.  
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What type of data is your column `3`? Try casting it to string with `df[3] = df[3].astype(str)`