# How to do a complicated filter in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, duplicates

I am trying to do a filter based on one column.  For example, I want to remove the transaction whenever I see it has account_no 1111

Input

```
Date        Trans   account_no
2017-12-11  10000   1111
2017-12-11  10000   1112
2017-12-11  10000   1113
2017-12-11  10001   1111
2017-12-11  10002   1113
```

Desired Output

```
Date        Trans   account_no
2017-12-11  10002   1113
```

Edit:

This is different than operator chaining because you are dealing with a duplication/conditional filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: filter rows of DataFrame with operator chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining)

Comment: Why `2017-12-11  10000   1113` is gone after the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `issubset` + `transform`

```
df[~df.groupby('Trans').account_no.transform(lambda x : set([1111]).issubset(x))]
Out[1658]: 
         Date  Trans  account_no
4  2017-12-11  10002        1113
```

Comment: do you know how to modify to the code to filter out for multiple numbers not just 1111 but lets you also add 1112

Comment: @ReeseFitzmaurice `df[~df.Trans.isin(df.loc[df.account_no.isin([1112,1111]),'Trans'])]`

Comment: I am still trying to keep the original question logic, would this work?
 df=df[~df.groupby('Trans').account_no.transform(lambda x : set([1112,1111]).issubset(x))]

Comment: @ReeseFitzmaurice this will not then , cause they will match both [1112 and 1111, when both condition satisfied, they will return true, seems like you need logic or rather than and right ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two steps. First find all `Trans` values that have an `account_no` that is ever equal to 1111 using `.loc`. Then select all other transactions with `isin()`

```
df[~df.Trans.isin(df.loc[df.account_no == 1111,'Trans'])]

         Date  Trans  account_no
4  2017-12-11  10002        1113
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` to filter based on a series.

```
def complex_filter_criteria(x):
    return x != 1111
df.loc[df['account_no'].apply(complex_filter_criteria)]
```

`df['account_no'].apply(complex_filter_criteria)` will return a series of `True/False` evaluations for each entry in the column `account_no`. Then, when you pass that into `df.loc`, it returns a dataframe consisting only of the rows corresponding to the `True` evaluations from the series.

[image]