# How to keep multiple values of same key while reading excel into dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to keep multiple values of same key while reading excel into dictionary using pandas. For ex I have below excel sheet **Data.xlsx**:

```
 Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
  A     1     2    3
  A     4     5    6
  B     7     8    9
```

Now i want to put index on **Col1** while reading this excel table in to dictionary using pandas but want to keep key **A** twice in the dictionary with multiple values. The output should look like:

```
 {A:{Col2:'1',Col3:'2',Col3:'3'}, A:{Col2:'4',Col3:'5',Col3:'6'},B:{Col2:'7',Col3:'8',Col3:'9'}
```

I used below code:

```
 Sheet = {}
 Data = {}
 xls = pd.ExcelFile('Data.xlsx')
 for i in xls.sheet_names:
    Sheet[i]= pd.read_excel(xls, i)
    Sheet[i].set_index('Col1',  inplace=True)
    Data[i] = Sheet[i].to_dict(orient='index')
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason I want to have multiple occurrence of same key with different values is because my further work is make a model based on values of other columns for **A**. I can't afford to loose the second row. If I have both rows for key **A**, I need to further analyze how the data is performing with respect to key **Col2**. Any further suggestions are more than welcome here if dictionary is not the best option.

Comment: this contradicts the nature of dictionary - it can't have duplicated keys. You can have a list instead of a dict

Comment: @MaxU So a simple answer to my question would be its not possible. Could you suggest any other alternative to my situation?

Comment: @MohitSharma, I have already done - use list/array of dicts instead of dict of dicts

Comment: It seems, you use already panda data frames. You can filter them directly and analyse the data from these filtered results, e.g. `df[df.Col1 == "A"]["Col2"].mean()`. See for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872393/8881141 or [this pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). numpy/scipy are also great tools to analyse array data.