# how to drop row base on lambda

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe in which I have to drop row if some of values.

for instance,

```
x not in ['N/A', ''] where x is columns
```

is there a way like, apply?

```
 df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

I am think in something like:

```
df.drop.apply(lambda x: X not in ['N/A', ''])???
```

My DF

```
     F   T   l
0    0   "0"   "0"
1    1   ""   "1"
2    2   "2"   ""
```

drop row if T == "" or l == ""

```
     F   T   l
0    0   "0"   "0"
```

I could not use

```
df.drop(df.T == "") since the condition ("") depend on runtime data
```

Comment: sample data, expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431561/1066110), the solution is:

```
 mask = df.pipe(lambda x: (x['T'].isin(['N/A', ''])) | (x['T'].isna()),)
 df.drop(df[mask].index, inplace=True)
```

this allow to provide different lambdas

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove any row that has `'N/A'` or `''` in the row then you can us a boolean index, just take the inverse of `isin()` e.g.:

```
In []:
df[~df.isin(['N/A', '']).any(axis=1)]

Out[]:
   F  T  l
0  0  0  0
```

If you need to limit to just columns `'A', 'l'` then select them, e.g.:

```
df[~df[['A', 'l']].isin(['N/A', '']).any(axis=1)]
```

You could also use a `dict` with `isin()` but that would only be useful if you had different values for the columns, e.g.:

```
df[~df.isin({'A': ['N/A', ''], 'l': ['']}).any(axis=1)]
```