# how to drop a row of a dataframe based on the sum of three columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe in the form of:

```
a   b   c  
89   9   2  
90   5   5  
10  70  20  
25  50  25
```

my goal is to remove the rows where 100 minus the sum of these three columns is greater than 0.5.

how can I do that?

Comment: Here are a few ways for you to filter out the rows from a [dataframe](https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe.html), and on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: I have added my solution as an answer. please check it out and see if it is a valid method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is what I came up with and it works just fine:

```
indexNames = df[((100 - df1['a'] - df['b'] - df['c']).abs() > 0.5)].index

df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

Comment: in the method that I have proposed, it can take care of any dataframe and it also considers absolute vale of the result so it would be more robust

Answer (score 4):

One solution:

```
(100 - df.sum(1)).le(0.5)
```

This is a boolean mask that you can give it to a dataframe:

```
df[(100 - df.sum(1)).le(0.5)]
```

Comment: Note the requirement is to remove the rows where .....

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I rectified it.